# Interrupt in Runnable interrupts other threads as well?

Tags: java, interrupt, runnable

I have a class `MyRunnable` that implements the `Runnable` interface. The class is instanciated from the main thread like this:

```
MyRunnable myRunnable = new MyRunnable();
Thread thread = new Thread( myRunnable );
thread.start();
```

`MyRunnable` implements a `stop()` method which stops the thread and also calls `interrupt()` on the current thread:

```
public void stop()
{
  LOG.info( "Stopping" );
  this.runService = false;  // reset running flag in order to stop the while-loop
  Thread.currentThread().interrupt();   // interrupt any blocking operations
}
```

However, interrupting the thread causes some major problems which I cannot understand. I noticed that not only this thread was interrupted but every other thread as well including the main thread! This caused broken database connections which have **nothing** to do with this thread, etc. When I remove the interrupt call then everything works as expected.

I thought that creating / starting / stopping a Runnable is quite simple but maybe I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: From what Thread are you calling the `stop()` method?

Comment: From the main thread.

Comment: `interrupt()` interrupts the one thread which you call it on, not just one you created previously.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're probably calling `myRunnable.stop()` from the main thread. This will cause `Thread.currentThread().interrupt()` to simply interrupt the main thread.

You should make no assumption about the calling thread in that method. If your intention is to actually interrupt the thread instantiated for executing your runnable, you should somehow pass that `thread` reference to your `Runnable` implementation and call `thread.interrupt()` instead of messing with the `currentThread()`.

Comment: Thanks, that sounds reasonable. If `MyRunnable` extends `java.lang.Thread` instead of implementing the `Runnable` interface would the call `Thread.currentThread().interrupt()` also interrupt the main thread or really **only** the current thread? I rather think about changing the class altogether because I need to catch a `InterruptException` inside.

Comment: @MarkusL You also need something which checks the interrupt flag. Unless you call such a method no InterruptedException will be thrown.